# Using different icons at tab bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use TabBar in my iOS project. My Icons have their own color and each icon has different color scheme when selected. But when i add icons, it converts into iOS own colors. I cant define each icon with different color. How can i use my icons with their own color?

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to ***Assets.xcassets*** folder in Xcode -> Select the image -> change the **rendering mode** to **Original Image**

[image]